# Expression for 'to persist through a situation unwillingly'

Tags: expressions, expression-choice

I want to express exactly that, i thought 'to grind sth through' was a valid expression but Google says no. So I am wondering how to express to see through an endeavor unwillingly.

Comment: Do you mean, "to grind one's teeth"?

Comment: According to this definition: https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/grind+one%27s+teeth, it seems like this idiom is more synonymous with 'sulk over'.

Answer (score 1):

I think the expression [grin and bear it](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/grin+and+bear+it) conveys the idea:

> To endure an unpleasant situation. *I hate having to work for rude people. I guess I have to grin and bear it*

(The Free Dictionary)